# Loading a database in memory

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

Is it possible to configure an environment where I can load a small database (i.e. 30 gigs) in memory.

If so, then how?

I ask because, I want to improve the speed of integration testing. I don't want to accept that integration tests have to be slow.

**NOTE:**

- I believe that each process is allocated a finite amount of memory.

Can I override this behavior and request more memory (i.e. 30 gigs) for a process if I have the RAM to satisfy the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this issue in a different way, by creating a RAM disk and creating the DB on the RAM disk. This has the advantage that as far as the DB thinks it is still on a disk, so nothing special is needed from the DB to support it, but everything is just done in memory.

This sped up integration tests significantly for me.

[Ramdisk](http://memory.dataram.com/products-and-services/software/ramdisk) do a 32gb and 64gb version which should meet your needs, although their product costs and you can apparantly achieve the same thing for free [using a windows system tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257405), but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Updated link: http://blog.laptopmag.com/faster-than-an-ssd-how-to-turn-extra-memory-into-a-ram-disk